# How to solve a linear system using Three Column Representation output vector as input data for Cholesky?

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I am trying to learn some methods in order to solve linear systems with Python. I have implemented a sort of these methods. Now I wish I could test them with large and sparse matrices. In order to do that I began to learn about Three Column Representation method cause I noticed that I am expected to reduce my sparse matrix before inputing it in my method. Three Column Representation seems to be simple but I cant figure out how to use its output as an input of my Cholesky method (for example). How do I use its output (a three column array with, values and references) as an input to my method? Do I need to rewrite my Cholesky method?

Here is my Cholesky method: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angellicacardozo/linear-algebra-methods/master/P03CHOLE.py

Thank you

Comment: Instead of link, Pleas share code here itself. It's more easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
For i = 1 To n
    For j = 1 To i
        Sum = a(i, j)
        For k = 1 To j-1
            Sum = Sum - a(i, k) * a(j, k)
        If i > j Then
            a(i, j) = Sum / a(j, j)
        Else If Sum > 0 Then
            a(i, i) = Sqrt(Sum)
        Else
            ERROR
```

Comment: Hmm sorry but I am not able to understand your answer without commets or something else :( What this pseudo code is meant to do or to be ?